# Activity life cycle - keeping a randomly generated image for a day

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a very simple Android app that's meant to be a 'nerdy' birthday gift, but have only few days left to get it done and absolutely no experience of doing it, so I thought I'd ask. I'm almost there in terms of coding content, but got really confused at the last hurdle.

The app is meant to do the following: it should issue a notification every 24 hours that a new photo awaits and the new photo should be chosen randomly from a database (images in the folder drawables). After clicking the notification, the user should be taken to the new randomly chosen photo. **Crucially, subsequent visits to the app throughout the day should result in seeing the same picture**, so that the user cannot just 'trick' the app into revealing the full database of images all at once. This particular feature is causing the headache really. At the moment the way I structure the code is as follows: I have a very simple MainActivity which just has a button in it. Clicking the button triggers the notifications every 24hours. The notification links to a different activity Repeating_activity, which generates a random image as you enter it. Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button2a;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button2a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


     button2a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,35);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReciever.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Then

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,Repeating_activity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"lala")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("New photo awaits!")
            .setContentTitle("New photo")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

}
}
```

And finally

```
public class Repeating_activity extends AppCompatActivity{

ImageView imageView2;

Random r;

Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.image_2,
        R.drawable.image_3,
        R.drawable.image_8,
};

int pickedImage = 0, lastPicked = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.repeating_activity);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    r = new Random();
    do {
        pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);
    } while (pickedImage == lastPicked);
    lastPicked = pickedImage;
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(images[pickedImage]).fit().centerInside().into(imageView2);
    imageView2.setImageResource(images[pickedImage]);
}
}
```

With some standard readjustments, such as changes in the AndroidManifest or introducing Picasso to avoid problems with bitmaps and dpi, this thing more or less works (tested on an emulator and my device). That is, the most basic idea behind the app works: notifications appear, which result in a random picture from the database being shown. For short while leaving the app and coming back to it also works in the sense that the photo is still being displayed. However, as soon as we terminate the app or let it be in the background for long enough, it reverts back to the main activity. Also, having checked with notification interval being only few minutes, there seems to be an issue with the fact that the same image is being shown for the subsequent 'days' (that's probably due to some bug in the code?).

I've started reading about life cycle of activities and the corresponding different states and also about how we can retrieve data 'lost' at the termination of an app (and also how usually this is being done automatically?). But as I said, this is a fun one-off little project, so trying to get to grips with all that seems a bit excessive.

In retrospect I also realise that it's probably better not to introduce the second activity at all. I would imagine the best way is to start with the main activity consisting of one fixed photo (e.g. a welcome image) and the button at the bottom. Clicking the button shouls start the the notifications appearing every 24hours and then every time a notification appears, it should link to the main activity but also change the image displayed to a new one. The new state of the MainActivity should be now saved so that re-entering app after terminating it should still result in seeing the randomly generated 'image of the day'.

It would be fascinating to spend another few days trying to uncover how to do it on my own, but I don't have much time, so any particular help will be greatly appreciated! What would be the quickest way to adjust this code to actually the feature described above? Thank you!

Comment: Think that you should focus on getting some 'long-term-memory' instead of trying to keep the Activity state forever (which is impossible btw). The simplest such memory is shared preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html. With this you can save the current image and day of year, for instance. Only allowing the image to change when day of year has changed.

Comment: The things you have read about life cycles and state, I would suspect is talking about changes in orientation for instance. Changing from portrait to landscape would terminate and re-create the activity. Here the state can be retained. But the same methods does not apply to a fully closed app that is being started again.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, managed to get it to work with your help! Sadly I don't have enough points to be able to endorse comments.

Comment: No problem :) glad to be able to point you in the right direction. Happy coding